# How many ways are there of sending 9 different books in 5 parcels with 4 of them having room for 2 books and 1 of them having room for 1 book?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Initially thought that it would be
$$(9C1)\cdot(8C1)\cdot(7C1)\cdot(6C1)\cdot(5C1)\cdot(4C1)\cdot(2C1)\cdot(1C1)$$ 
but I soon realised that it was restricting its order and thus creating additional combinations. I’ve been trying it for an hour now but I still can’t seem to come up with an intuition behind this. ANY help would be greatly appreciated . Also I am sorry for not using the symbols properly. I’m new to maths  stackexchange and I’m still struggling with mathjax. I’ll soon update the answer with apropriate symbols

EDIT: I realised I made a mistake in the answer. Here is the updated version 
$$9 \cdot 7 \cdot 5 \cdot 3 = 945$$

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on MathJax.

Comment: Why are you using permutations?  Are the parcels addressed to different recipients?  If not, it is just a matter of which books are placed in which parcel.

Comment: Oop! I made a mistake and yes you’re right, the answer is 9*7*5*3 =945 but still can comprehend how?

Answer (score 0):

Hint. The answer can be written as
$$9\cdot \frac{\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}}{4!}\quad \mbox{or}\quad \frac{\binom{9}{2}\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}}{4!}\cdot 1.$$
Can you picture what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be approached in various ways.  Your answer is equivalent to those proposed by @RobertZ.

Line up the books in some order (alphabetically or largest to smallest, it does not matter).  We can select which book is placed in the parcel that has room for one book in $9$ ways.  That leaves us with eight books to place in four parcels, each of which can contain two books.  Take the first book left in the line and match it with one of the other seven books.  Place them in a parcel.  That leaves us with six books.  Take the first book left in the line and match it with one of the other five books.  Place those books in a parcel.  That leaves us with four books.  Take the first book left in the line and match it with one of the other three books.  Place those books in a parcel.  The final two books must be placed in the remaining parcel.  Hence, the number of ways to place the books in the parcels is 
$$9 \cdot 7 \cdot 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 1$$